# random Points In Polygon С#?(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d, случайные-числа, polygon

Я знаю о [последовательности Хэлтона](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence) . Но пока я не могу найти формулы, по которым генерируются точки. Также беспокоит вопрос, последовательность Халтона генерирует точки только в прямоугольнике? Или я могу генерировать точки в любом многоугольнике, используя последовательность Хэлтона? Если последовательность Хэлтона генерирует точки только в прямоугольнике, каким другим способом можно создать точки в многоугольнике?

Я так же попытался вытащить из [JTS Test Builder](https://github.com/locationtech/jts)(написанном на java). Методы генерирующие случайные точки в полигоне:

```
  public static Geometry randomPointsInPolygon(Geometry g, int nPts) {
    RandomPointsBuilder shapeBuilder = new RandomPointsBuilder(FunctionsUtil.getFactoryOrDefault(g));
    shapeBuilder.setExtent(g);
    shapeBuilder.setNumPoints(nPts);
    return shapeBuilder.getGeometry();
  }

  public void setNumPoints(int numPts) { this.numPts = numPts; }

  public static GeometryFactory getFactoryOrDefault(Geometry g)
  {
    if (g == null) return JTSTestBuilder.getGeometryFactory();
    return g.getFactory();
  }
  public static GeometryFactory getGeometryFactory() 
  { 
    /**
     * Allow this to work even if TestBuilder is not initialized
     */
    if (instance() == null) 
      return new GeometryFactory();
    return model().getGeometryFactory();
  }

  public void setExtent(Geometry mask)
  {
    if (! (mask instanceof Polygonal))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only polygonal extents are supported");
    this.maskPoly = mask;
    setExtent(mask.getEnvelopeInternal());
    extentLocator = new IndexedPointInAreaLocator(mask);
  }

  public Geometry getGeometry()
  {
    Coordinate[] pts = new Coordinate[numPts];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numPts) {
        Coordinate p = createRandomCoord(getExtent());
        if (extentLocator != null && ! isInExtent(p))
            continue;
        pts[i++] = p;
    }
    return geomFactory.createMultiPointFromCoords(pts);
  }
```

И нашёл похожий [вопрос на форуме](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6412/generate-points-that-lie-inside-polygon).

Мне нужен быстрый алгоритм на C# для генерации точек в полигоне. Так как эта операция будет вызываться много раз.

Comment: Так там же и ответ есть. Чем не подошел?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Мало ли у кого скрипт есть готовый, быстро работающий . Мне важна скорость выполнения методов ... Ищу и пишу сам ,самый быстрый вариант

Comment: @IvanTriumphov а зачем Вам случайные точки в полигоне понадобились?)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q У меня есть площадные координаты и внутри этой площади на до разместить деревья

Comment: я так и подумал почему-то. Но ведь деревья имеют не случайное распределение а более менее равномерное. т.е. случайные точки с высокой долей вероятности будут слишком близко. в целом для этого лучше использовать какой нибудь posson disc sampling

Comment: забыл добавить - на мой взгляд неплохо получится если использовать затайленый шаблон шума, который наложен на целевой многоугольник

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Мне надо чтоб леса выглядели по разному . Разве шаблон шума поможет сделать это ?